# selenium execution hanging for 3 hours in saucelabs and on premises

Tags: java, selenium, saucelabs

The test cases are hanging for 3 hrs in sauce. I have tried solutions for TCP connection issue in sauce with selenium(using selenium and java) versions 3.11.0 , 3.141.59. But it is not working. I am triggering the test suite from eclipse with sauce labs and Azure Devops with sauce labs. If any one knows the answer Please share the solutions to reduce the socket time.

Please find the socket timeout code I have tried.

```
ApacheHttpClient.Factory clientFactory = new ApacheHttpClient.Factory(new HttpClientFactory(1000, 3600));
  hubURL = new URL("http://" + driverHost + ":" + driverPort + "/wd/hub");
HttpCommandExecutor executor = new HttpCommandExecutor(new HashMap<String, CommandInfo>(), hubURL, clientFactory);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "hanging?" What exactly is not working? Are you seeing an error? If it ran on Sauce, what is the URL?

Comment: When the test cases are running in sauce , in between it failed to find the elements saying it didn't receive any comments till the mentioned time(I have mentioned 180 seconds) and test ends there in sauce videos. But the element was still available in the page. I am using 3 threads. After the test case ends with the time out error, one thread is not accessible in sauce. only 2 threads are active. The one thread which failed waited for 3 hrs 27 mins and ended.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time following what you are saying. I work at Sauce, if you give me the URL to a 3+ hour test I can try to see what is happening from our side.

Comment: I can't share you the URL.But the issue is happening in the combination of selenium+Sauce.Sauce videos are not running for 3 hrs.Selenium test cases when running in local machines are usually timed out in few seconds if the driver is not receiving any commands.But while running in sauce, the timeout is not happening as expected.It is taking 3 hrs to timed out from the case.The videos are ending on time.But the connection is not getting closed.Any solution to reduce this 3 hr time out will be helpful.Desired capabilites for max duration, idle timeout and command timeout are tried for solutions.

Comment: I can't help you without looking at an example of what you are seeing. Please contact support: https://saucelabs.com/training-support